# Comparing simple slopes with one another (in R)

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc

I know I can break an interaction effect to create some [simple slopes](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/how-do-i-make-graphs-of-simple-slopes-in-excel/) (plot below). I also know I can test whether each of these simple slopes (in my case $6$) is significantly different from $0$ or not (see `sim_slope` line).

> **Question:** BUT, how can I test whether the simple slopes are significantly different from each other in a pairwise manner?

I appreciate an `R` solution.

```
data <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/salary.csv')
m <- lm(salary ~ time*pubs*female, data = data)

library(interactions)

#Test whether each simple slope is different from 0:
sim_slopes(m, pred = time, modx = pubs, mod2 = female, john = F)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be more comparisons than you want. But the point is you need to use `at` to specify the covariate values to use. I also suggest NOT using 2-sided formulas to specify desired contrasts.

```r
require(emmeans)

# obtain means +- 1 SD
(m.pm.sd <- lapply(data[, c("pubs", "time")], function(x) mean(x) + c(-1, 1)*sd(x)))
#> $pubs
#> [1]  5.348203 33.909862
#> 
#> $time
#> [1]  3.312931 12.848359

# slopes for 'time'
(emt.t <- emtrends(m, ~ pubs | female, var = "time", at = m.pm.sd))
#> female = 0:
#>   pubs time.trend  SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   5.35       1366 448 54      467     2264
#>  33.91       2399 548 54     1300     3498
#> 
#> female = 1:
#>   pubs time.trend  SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   5.35      -1723 557 54    -2839     -607
#>  33.91        218 285 54     -352      789
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: time 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95

pairs(emt.t, simple = "each")
#> $`simple contrasts for pubs`
#> female = 0:
#>  contrast                            estimate  SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  5.34820265575885 - 33.9098618603702    -1033 572 54 -1.807  0.0763 
#> 
#> female = 1:
#>  contrast                            estimate  SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  5.34820265575885 - 33.9098618603702    -1942 643 54 -3.018  0.0039 
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: time 
#> 
#> $`simple contrasts for female`
#> pubs =  5.35:
#>  contrast estimate  SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  0 - 1        3089 715 54 4.320   0.0001 
#> 
#> pubs = 33.91:
#>  contrast estimate  SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  0 - 1        2180 618 54 3.530   0.0009 
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: time


# slopes for 'pubs'
(emt.p <- emtrends(m, ~ time| female, var = "pubs", at = m.pm.sd))
#> female = 0:
#>   time pubs.trend  SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   3.31       -147 183 54   -514.5   221.24
#>  12.85        198 112 54    -26.0   422.57
#> 
#> female = 1:
#>   time pubs.trend  SE df lower.CL upper.CL
#>   3.31       -499 245 54   -989.4    -9.01
#>  12.85        149 107 54    -65.7   363.64
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: pubs 
#> Confidence level used: 0.95

pairs(emt.p, simple = "each")
#> $`simple contrasts for time`
#> female = 0:
#>  contrast                            estimate  SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  3.31293138434118 - 12.8483589382395     -345 191 54 -1.807  0.0763 
#> 
#> female = 1:
#>  contrast                            estimate  SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  3.31293138434118 - 12.8483589382395     -648 215 54 -3.018  0.0039 
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: pubs 
#> 
#> $`simple contrasts for female`
#> time =  3.31:
#>  contrast estimate  SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  0 - 1       352.6 306 54 1.153   0.2539 
#> 
#> time = 12.85:
#>  contrast estimate  SE df t.ratio p.value
#>  0 - 1        49.3 155 54 0.319   0.7513 
#> 
#> Results are averaged over the levels of: pubs
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I guess you wanted to include tge means too, so change c(-1,1) to c(-1,0,1)

Comment: Well, the model you are using fits a different `time` trend for each combination of `pubs` and `female`. Is it your intention to ignore those differences? It's your research; I just showed you how to do it, you can choose different `at` values, whcich of course you will have to justify. Please read again the vignettes for "contrasts" and "interactions" to see how to construct the contrasts you need for various complex hypotheses -- or to average them together, if that is what you're asking. Everything comes out as an `emmGrid` object, on which you can run `emmeans()`, `contrast()`, etc.