# How to 2 compare slopes from different datasets?

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme

I am still quite new to this and I'm unsure how to structure my question.

I have these two mixed models that I am using to generate a linear regression plot

```
    control<- lmer(OUTPUT~ Weeks +(1|ID), data = CONTROL, REML=FALSE)

    group1<- lmer(OUTPUT~ Weeks +(1|ID), data = group1, REML=FALSE)
```

I have plotted these regressions and I want know how to compare if these regression slopes are significantly different to each other. I want to reduce type 1 error as much as possible. I have been advised to use to compare:

```
    model<-lmer(OUTPUT ~ (1|ID) + Category*Weeks, data=dataCom, REML=FALSE)
```

Where category is just group1 and control.
It states that my results are not significantly different.

```
  Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error t value
    (Intercept)       1.725874   0.267075   6.462
    CategoryGrp1        0.070358   0.342234   0.206
    Weeks             0.004657   0.008774   0.531
    CategoryGrp1:Weeks -0.011728   0.011318  -1.036
```

But when I go to plot the regressions together I see that the slopes do not intercept.

Is there another way to compare the slope of my graphs? I have tried anova however, I have more control data than group1 so it does not allow for a comparison.

I appreciate the help.
Thank you

Comment: Can you post the R outputs for your models? Is the interaction term in the last model significant?

Comment: @Sointu I have done so thank you for your help

Comment: I'm sorry but it seems the effect of category, weeks, or their interaction are not significant (you can get p-values by loading the lmerTest package and then running the analysis again, but based on the estimate and Std. error sizes they are not significant). So you shouldn't consider comparing the slopes because your results suggest no interaction (and no main effects either). I'm not sure what you mean by your slopes not intercepting, but the slopes can be non-parallel (and typically are) without the interaction effect being significant, which seems to be the case here.

Comment: However if you want to compare your simple slopes in any case, I think the advice in this reply is excellent: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483488/comparing-simple-slopes-with-one-another-in-r Just ignore the "pubs" variable in the example, replace gender with your group vs. contrast and "time" with your Weeks.

Comment: @Sointu - since my fixed term interactions are insignificant, should I no longer use LME4 to plot my data? I am not getting significant interactions anywhere. I only get significant interaction in lm for my intercept - not my slope

Comment: lme4 is not used for plotting. It's used to run multilevel regression models, as you have done. And yes, because it seems your group x weeks interaction is not significant, you don't need to / you shouldn't compare your simple slopes for group1 and control. Unfortunately it seems to me your main effects (Weeks and Group) are not significant either, but that's a different issue.

Comment: @Sointu since my main effects are not significant - should I not use multilevel regression models further? would it be better to use lm instead?

Comment: Having significant interaction effects and using lm vs. lmer are not related. You use lm or lmer to see whether your predictors or their interactions are related to your outcome (i.e., are significant or not). Roughly, if you have non-clustered data, you'd use lm for this purpose, if you have clustered data (for instance, several observations from the same participants, as I think you have), you should use lmer.

Comment: Unfortunately your Weeks and Group or their interaction do not seem to be related to your output, ie. you don't seem to have significant results. This is unrelated to the choice of model.

Comment: I meant to say in the first comment "Having significant main effects or interaction effects and using lm vs. lmer are not related". Whether you should use lm or lmer has nothing to do with whether you get significant or non-significant effects with either one of them.